How can I get an Edge's Bevel Weight attribute value via Python?
How can I get an edge's bevel weight attribute value? For example, I want to retrieve the bevel_weight_edge value from the edge at index 0.

I expected it to be something like this:
C.object.data.edges[0].attributes['bevel_weight_edge']

to return the float value.

Hello there is no attributes on C.object.data.edges[0]. Please can you provide a screenshot of the value in the UI you are trying to retrieve. Is this what you are trying to get?

Hi, yeah i know attributes in edge data is not available,
i mean that just an expected code for easy understanding.
the value i want to retrive is Mean Bevel Weight as its a built-in Attribute,
but sometimes i need to retrive value from custom attribute as well

From https://b3d.interplanety.org/en/working-with-mean-bevel-weight-using-the-blender-python-api/:

To interact with the Bevel modifier, which creates a bevel on
specified edges, each of the required edges must be given a specific
numeric weight parameter ranging from 0.0 to 1.0. In manual mode, the
weight for the bevel is set in the N-panel on the Item tab in Edges
Data > Mean Bevel Weight field.
The Mean Bevel Weight values ​​for edge weights are stored in a mesh
bevel_weight_edge attribute. The moment we set weights through the
UI panel, Blender automatically creates this attribute and sets the
values ​​we specify into it.
To read the given values ​​of weights from the edges, we must first
“evaluate” the mesh – using a depsgraph, obtain the final copy of
the mesh data having applied all modifiers, geometry nodes and all
other dynamical changes.

Here's a sample function I derived from the data I gathered from the link:
import bpy

obj = bpy.data.objects['Cube']
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
  
def get_bevel_weight(obj, edge_index):
    obj_data = obj.evaluated_get(bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()).data
    if not 'bevel_weight_edge' in obj_data.attributes:
        return 0.0
    attr = obj_data.attributes['bevel_weight_edge']
    return attr.data[edge_index].value

edge_index = 0
bevel_weight = get_bevel_weight(obj, edge_index)
print(bevel_weight)


Thank you,
Its work as expected,
Is there any other way without switching to object mode?
Since this script it's mostly used in Edit Mode for example to get Value from selected Edges.

@CheatPekalongan As far as I know, you cannot evaluate a mesh in Edit Mode in the same way you can in Object Mode. In Edit Mode, mesh data is in a temporary, editable state that does not include all the final results of modifiers and other applied changes.

@HarryMcKenzie you have to get the bmesh in order to access the values. See my answer. Cheers

Edit mode
Similar to Manually setting custom attributes per edge / vertex / etc
import bpy
import bmesh

mesh = bpy.data.objects["Cube"].data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(mesh)
layer = bm.edges.layers.float.get("bevel_weight_edge")

for edge in bm.edges:
    if edge.select:
        print(f"Bevel value at edge index {edge.index} : {edge[layer]}")

# Alternatively
print(f"Bevel value at edge index 0 : {edges[0][layer]}")

In edit mode the regular interface to access attributes is not available since the construct is a bmesh, not a mesh. You have to use the special bmesh interface to access the values.
Note you can't access all attribute types in edit mode. eg How can I access and modify a boolean attribute in edit mode?

Cool thank you for sharing! It is quite unintuitive the way they implemented this API.

@HarryMcKenzie Cheers. Yeah if I remember correctly from a dev post I saw it's a problem of using a legacy system and the devs want to get rid of the bmesh implementation altogether in the future, I assume that means a LOT of refactoring.
